# Sharepoint 2013 multiple stages task

Tags: tasks, task-list

I just finished setting up a new team site on SharePoint and now I need to edit the functionality of the task list.

Basically what I want to do is to create a task with multiple stages (as sub-tasks or whatever) and by that, fill the percentage of the root task.
Is it possible?

Here is a demo of what I did so far :

[image: referring to test mission as root and troubleshooting as sub-task]